# trying to install puppet 3.8 on centos

Tags: centos, puppet

I am trying to install an older version of puppet,

1) i installed puppet-devel repo 
2) i did yum update and then ran yum install puppet --skip-broken I get the following error:

```
Packages skipped because of dependency problems: 
1:facter-2.0.1-0.1rc4.el6.x86_64 from puppetlabs-devel 
hiera-1.3.2-0.1rc2.el6.noarch from puppetlabs-devel 
libselinux-ruby-2.2.2-6.el7.x86_64 from base 
puppet-3.6.0-0.1rc1.el6.noarch from puppetlabs-devel 
ruby-2.0.0.598-25.el7_1.x86_64 from base
```

So i managed to install most of the dependencies , however i still have an error when trying to install puppet :

```
repository 'puppetlabs-devel': Error parsing config: Error parsing "baseurl = 'https://yum.puppetlabs.com/<%= @dist.downcase -%>/<%= @codename -%>/devel/x86_64'": URL must be http, ftp, file or https not ""
```

..... I did tamper with the repo , so i'll put the repo output here:

```
[root@localhost bin]# cat /etc/yum.repos.d/puppetlabs-devel.repo
[puppetlabs-devel]
name=Puppet Labs Devel 6 - $basearch
baseurl=http://yum.puppetlabs.com/el/6/devel/$basearch
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-puppetlabs-devel
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
```

please do tell if you can point me to the correct repo for the version i need.   The docs suggest i use yum.puppetlabs.com , but i'm unsure how to as i tried the rpm method and didnt get far

Answer (score 0):

The error you've provided doesn't match the repo configuration you've pasted - the error suggests you've got some other definition of `puppetlabs-devel` that contains some ERB (`<%` etc).

I'd suggest searching /etc/yum.conf and /etc/yum.repos.d/ more thoroughly and delete any other instances of the repository (`grep -r puppetlabs-devel /etc/yum*`).

You should also be using the non-devel repo, since the devel one only contains release candidates and pre-release software. Use the instructions from [Pre-4.0 Open Source Repositories](https://docs.puppet.com/guides/puppetlabs_package_repositories.html#pre-40-open-source-repositories) to configure it.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to overcome this issue by downloading the correct devel repo and having the repo for the dependencies also enabled , the devel repo has the following content :

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/yum.repos.d/puppetlabs-devel.repo
[puppetlabs-devel]
name=Puppet Labs Devel 6 - $basearch
baseurl=http://yum.puppetlabs.com/el/7/products/$basearch
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-puppetlabs-devel
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1

[puppetlabs-devel-dep]
name=Puppet Labs Devel 6 - $basearch
baseurl=http://yum.puppetlabs.com/el/7/dependencies/$basearch
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-puppetlabs-devel
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
```